# Laravel query using whereIn not working when insert array of data

Tags: laravel

I try to get data for promotion using whereIn, but the query give error.
In whereIn, if I make whereIn('category_id', [123,2323]) no error.

But when I try to get data from request($data2 = $request->category;), I cannot use with whereIn

```
  $promotions = Promotion::with('product')->with('category')->whereHas(
        'category',
        function ($q) {
            $data2 = $request->category;

            $q->whereIn('category_id', $data2);
        })
        ->paginate(9);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `use($request)`

```
$promotions = Promotion::with('product')->with('category')->whereHas(
    'category',
    function ($q) use ($request){
        $data2 = $request->category;

        $q->whereIn('category_id', $data2);
    })
    ->paginate(9);
```

Sample data for $request->category. I return data as json and display using javascript console.log()

[image]

Comment: share what value you have in `$request->category` ?

Comment: I had add value for $request->category in the question